# ResourceExhaustedError while generating tf records in VGGish model

Tags: runtime-error, data-science, vgg-net

I have been working with the VGGish model. When I change the size of the window of the spectrogram produced, a lot of them are produced. When I produce the tf-records, I then get the error of -

Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[24373,64,96,64] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[node vggish/conv1/Conv2D (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]`

I read stack overflow for a possible solution, some said that changing the batch size might help. Since I am new to data science, I really don't know how to do that. Can someone help me a little more with the problem?

Here is my code.

````
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# ==============================================================================

r"""A simple demonstration of running VGGish in inference mode.

This is intended as a toy example that demonstrates how the various building
blocks (feature extraction, model definition and loading, postprocessing) work
together in an inference context.

A WAV file (assumed to contain signed 16-bit PCM samples) is read in, converted
into log mel spectrogram examples, fed into VGGish, the raw embedding output is
whitened and quantized, and the postprocessed embeddings are optionally written
in a SequenceExample to a TFRecord file (using the same format as the embedding
features released in AudioSet).

Usage:
  # Run a WAV file through the model and print the embeddings. The model
  # checkpoint is loaded from vggish_model.ckpt and the PCA parameters are
  # loaded from vggish_pca_params.npz in the current directory.
  $ python vggish_inference_demo.py --wav_file /path/to/a/wav/file

  # Run a WAV file through the model and also write the embeddings to
  # a TFRecord file. The model checkpoint and PCA parameters are explicitly
  # passed in as well.
  $ python vggish_inference_demo.py --wav_file /path/to/a/wav/file \
                                    --tfrecord_file /path/to/tfrecord/file \
                                    --checkpoint /path/to/model/checkpoint \
                                    --pca_params /path/to/pca/params

  # Run a built-in input (a sine wav) through the model and print the
  # embeddings. Associated model files are read from the current directory.
  $ python vggish_inference_demo.py
"""

from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import six
import soundfile
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()

import vggish_input
import vggish_params
import vggish_postprocess
import vggish_slim

flags = tf.app.flags

flags.DEFINE_string(
    'wav_file', 'input.wav',
    'Path to a wav file. Should contain signed 16-bit PCM samples. '
    'If none is provided, a synthetic sound is used.')

flags.DEFINE_string(
    'checkpoint', 'vggish_model.ckpt',
    'Path to the VGGish checkpoint file.')

flags.DEFINE_string(
    'pca_params', 'vggish_pca_params.npz',
    'Path to the VGGish PCA parameters file.')

flags.DEFINE_string(
    'tfrecord_file', 'records_for_0.025sec_window.tfrecord',
    'Path to a TFRecord file where embeddings will be written.')

FLAGS = flags.FLAGS

# function to make the postproces and add it to the file 

def main(_):
  # In this simple example, we run the examples from a single audio file through
  # the model. If none is provided, we generate a synthetic input.
  if FLAGS.wav_file:
    wav_file = FLAGS.wav_file
  else:
    # Write a WAV of a sine wav into an in-memory file object.
    num_secs = 5
    freq = 1000
    sr = 44100
    t = np.linspace(0, num_secs, int(num_secs * sr))
    x = np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * t)
    # Convert to signed 16-bit samples.
    samples = np.clip(x * 32768, -32768, 32767).astype(np.int16)
    wav_file = six.BytesIO()
    soundfile.write(wav_file, samples, sr, format='WAV', subtype='PCM_16')
    wav_file.seek(0)
  examples_batch = vggish_input.wavfile_to_examples(wav_file)
  print(examples_batch)
  print("I reached step 1. ", examples_batch.shape)

  # Prepare a postprocessor to munge the model embeddings.
  pproc = vggish_postprocess.Postprocessor(FLAGS.pca_params)

  # If needed, prepare a record writer to store the postprocessed embeddings.
  writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(
      FLAGS.tfrecord_file) if FLAGS.tfrecord_file else None

  with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    # Define the model in inference mode, load the checkpoint, and
    # locate input and output tensors.
    vggish_slim.define_vggish_slim(training=False)
    vggish_slim.load_vggish_slim_checkpoint(sess, FLAGS.checkpoint)
    features_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(
        vggish_params.INPUT_TENSOR_NAME)
    embedding_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(
        vggish_params.OUTPUT_TENSOR_NAME)

    print("I reached step 2")

    # Run inference and postprocessing.
    [embedding_batch1] = sess.run([embedding_tensor],
                                 feed_dict={features_tensor: examples_batch[0:6000,:,:]})

    postprocessed_batch = pproc.postprocess(embedding_batch1) 
    print("I reached step 3", postprocessed_batch.shape)
    # Write the postprocessed embeddings as a SequenceExample, in a similar
    # format as the features released in AudioSet. Each row of the batch of
    # embeddings corresponds to roughly a second of audio (96 10ms frames), and
    # the rows are written as a sequence of bytes-valued features, where each
    # feature value contains the 128 bytes of the whitened quantized embedding.
    seq_example1 = tf.train.SequenceExample(
        feature_lists=tf.train.FeatureLists(
            feature_list={
                vggish_params.AUDIO_EMBEDDING_FEATURE_NAME:
                    tf.train.FeatureList(
                        feature=[
                            tf.train.Feature(
                                bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(
                                    value=[embedding.tobytes()]))
                            for embedding in postprocessed_batch
                        ]
                    )
            }
        )
    )

    [embedding_batch1] = sess.run([embedding_tensor],
                                 feed_dict={features_tensor: examples_batch[6000:12000,:,:]})

    postprocessed_batch = pproc.postprocess(embedding_batch1) 
    print("I reached step 3", postprocessed_batch.shape)
    # Write the postprocessed embeddings as a SequenceExample, in a similar
    # format as the features released in AudioSet. Each row of the batch of
    # embeddings corresponds to roughly a second of audio (96 10ms frames), and
    # the rows are written as a sequence of bytes-valued features, where each
    # feature value contains the 128 bytes of the whitened quantized embedding.
    seq_example2 = tf.train.SequenceExample(
        feature_lists=tf.train.FeatureLists(
            feature_list={
                vggish_params.AUDIO_EMBEDDING_FEATURE_NAME:
                    tf.train.FeatureList(
                        feature=[
                            tf.train.Feature(
                                bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(
                                    value=[embedding.tobytes()]))
                            for embedding in postprocessed_batch
                        ]
                    )
            }
        )
    )

    if writer:
      writer.write(seq_example1.SerializeToString())
      writer.write(seq_example2.SerializeToString())

  if writer:
    writer.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.app.run()```
````

Comment: Hi Tushar, based on the size of the tensor, I tend to agree that you will likely need to either reduce your batch size or limit the size of the network altogether. Would you be able to paste the code you are using? That would make it easier for us to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @BrandonSchabell here is my code. I posted the code that I am using. On your advice, I tried to reduce the number of spectrograms it is dealing with at a time to 6000 and then printing the data in the tf file. But it seems like there is no way to append that file. Like every time I write it, it is erased first and then adds 6000 records and by the end of it i am left with 6000 tf recods.